# Is "Number Second" correct as in "he became number second"?

Tags: grammar

I came across the following:

> At the beginning of the year, when we introduced the login feature with email and phone, email was number one. When we added *Sign in with Google* in May, it took off becoming number one and email becoming **number second**.

Is *number second* grammatically correct in this context?

Comment: I don't think it is grammatical in *any* context. It's either "second" or "number two".

Comment: I'm guessing it was used somewhat tongue-in-cheek.  (I would have used "number tooth".)

Comment: Though one can see how the original "becoming number one and email becoming second" might have been erroneously edited.

Comment: @HotLicks Would that tooth bite your tongue?

Comment: @BoldBen - I'm counting on it not to.

Answer (score 0):

When we enumerate items it is conventional to keep the same construction throughout the list: *number 1*, *number 2*, ... ; *the first*, *the second*, *the third* ... .

Mixing the forms of construction is at least bad style, and perhaps ungrammatical. Furthermore, *number first*,  *number second* ... is not conventionally used in listing; I have never encountered it. Adjectives like *First* and *Second* are two of many adjectives that are not enumerable in this way. *Number green*, *number red* ... ? Almost meaningless.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think so. I've search for usage of the phrase "number second" but couldn't fine any credible source opting to use it. I believe that "second" would fit better:"When we added Sign in with Google in May, it took off becoming number one and email becoming the second."
But since English isn't my native language, I'm not so certain about it.